# How to get local Github branch in Visual Studio to sync with online repository

Tags: github, visual-studio

I've gotten into Github and Visual Studio 2013 Team Services enough to a be able to create repository on Github and sync it to Visual Studio, and I've started familiarizing myself with the various controls.

I can create a local branch, and I can create a remote branch.  However, I can't figure out how to link and sync a new local branch with a new remote branch.

Do I start at the Github site, or start within VS, and go where from there?

I've looked at it a bunch of different ways within Team Services and Github, and tried googling around for it, however I can't find the right combination of actions.

Comment: Use `git` on the command line. Read the [`git` documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc). Look their  [video](https://git-scm.com/videos)